# News article extract using requests,bs4 and newspaper packages. why doesn't links=soup.select(".r a") find anything?. This code was working earlier

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-newspaper, newspaper3k

Objective: I am trying to download the news article based on the keywords to perform sentiment analysis.

This code was working a few months ago but now it returns a null value. I tried fixing the issue but`links=soup.select(".r a")` return null value.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string
import nltk
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys
import webbrowser
import newspaper 
import time
from newspaper import Article

Company_name1 =[]
Article_number1=[]
Article_Title1=[]
Article_Authors1=[]
Article_pub_date1=[]
Article_Text1=[]
Article_Summary1=[]
Article_Keywords1=[]
Final_dataframe=[]

class Newspapr_pd:
    def __init__(self,term):
        self.term=term
        self.subjectivity=0
        self.sentiment=0
        self.url='https://www.google.com/search?q={0}&safe=active&tbs=qdr:w,sdb:1&tbm=nws&source=lnt&dpr=1'.format(self.term)
    
    def NewsArticlerun_pd(self):
        response=requests.get(self.url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        #print(response.text)
        soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
        links=soup.select(".r a")
       
        numOpen = min(5, len(links))
        Article_number=0
        for i in range(numOpen):
            response_links = webbrower.open("https://www.google.com" + links[i].get("href"))
            
            
            
        #For different language newspaper refer above table 
            article = Article(response_links, language="en") # en for English 
            Article_number+=1
            
            print('*************************************************************************************')
            
            Article_number1.append(Article_number)
            Company_name1.append(self.term)

        #To download the article 
            try:

                article.download() 
                 #To parse the article 
                article.parse() 
                #To perform natural language processing ie..nlp 
                article.nlp() 
  
        #To extract title
                Article_Title1.append(article.title)

  
        #To extract text
                Article_Text1.append(article.text)

  
        #To extract Author name
                Article_Authors1.append(article.authors)

                
        #To extract article published date
                Article_pub_date1.append(article.publish_date)
                

                
        #To extract summary
                Article_Summary1.append(article.summary)
                

  
        #To extract keywords 
                Article_Keywords1.append(article.keywords)

            except:
                print('Error in loading page')
                continue
  
        for art_num,com_name,title,text,auth,pub_dt,summaries,keywds in zip(Article_number1,Company_name1,Article_Title1,Article_Text1,Article_Authors1,Article_pub_date1,Article_Summary1,Article_Keywords1):
            Final_dataframe.append({'Article_link_num':art_num, 'Company_name':com_name,'Article_Title':title,'Article_Text':text,'Article_Author':auth,
                                   'Article_Published_date':pub_dt,'Article_Summary':summaries,'Article_Keywords':keywds})
        
list_of_companies=['Amazon','Jetairways','nirav modi']

for i in list_of_companies:
    comp = str('"'+ i + '"')
    a=Newspapr_pd(comp)
    a.NewsArticlerun_pd()

Final_new_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Final_dataframe)
Final_new_dataframe.tail()
```

Comment: sites that use class names with no semantic value (eg `iRPxbe` or `FAkayc`) change their html often. you're lucky to have only one selector to change

Comment: Did my answer and overview document help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very complex issue, because Google News continually changes their class names. Additionally Google will add various prefixes to article urls and throw in some hidden ad or social media tags.

The answer below only addresses scraping articles from Google news. More testing is needed to determine how it works with a large amount of keywords and with Google News changing page structure.

The `Newspaper3k` extraction is even more complex, because each article can have a different structure. I would recommend looking at my [Newspaper3k Usage Overview](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) document for details on how to design that part of your code.

P.S. I'm current writing a [new news scraper](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newshound), because the development for [Newspaper3k](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper) is dead. I'm unsure of the release date of my code.

```
import requests
import re as regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_google_news_article(search_string):
    articles = []
    url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search_string}&safe=active&tbs=qdr:w,sdb:1&tbm=nws&source=lnt&dpr=1'
    response = requests.get(url)
    raw_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    main_tag = raw_html.find('div', {'id': 'main'})
    for div_tag in main_tag.find_all('div', {'class': regex.compile('xpd')}):
        for a_tag in div_tag.find_all('a', href=True):
            if not a_tag.get('href').startswith('/search?'):
                none_articles = bool(regex.search('amazon.com|facebook.com|twitter.com|youtube.com|wikipedia.org', a_tag['href']))
                if none_articles is False:
                    if a_tag.get('href').startswith('/url?q='):
                        find_article = regex.search('(.*)(&sa=)', a_tag.get('href'))
                        article = find_article.group(1).replace('/url?q=', '')
                        if article.startswith('https://'):
                            articles.append(article)

    return articles

                

list_of_companies = ['amazon', 'jet airways', 'nirav modi']
for company_name in list_of_companies:
    print(company_name)
    search_results = get_google_news_article(company_name)
    for item in sorted(set(search_results)):
        print(item)
    print('\n')
```

This is the output from the code above:

```
amazon
https://9to5mac.com/2021/11/15/amazon-releases-native-prime-video-app-for-macos-with-purchase-support-and-more/
https://wtvbam.com/2021/11/15/india-police-to-question-amazon-executives-in-probe-over-marijuana-smuggling/
https://www.cnet.com/home/smart-home/all-the-new-amazon-features-for-your-smart-home-alexa-disney-echo/
https://www.cnet.com/tech/amazon-unveils-black-friday-deals-starting-on-nov-25/
https://www.crossroadstoday.com/i/amazons-best-black-friday-deals-for-2021-2/
https://www.reuters.com/technology/ibm-amazon-partner-extend-reach-data-tools-oil-companies-2021-11-15/
https://www.theverge.com/2021/11/15/22783275/amazon-basics-smart-switches-price-release-date-specs
https://www.tomsguide.com/news/amazon-echo-motion-detection
https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/shopping/2021/11/15/amazon-black-friday-2021-deals-online/8623710002/
https://www.winknews.com/2021/11/15/new-amazon-sortation-center-began-operations-monday-could-bring-faster-deliveries/

jet airways
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/expert-view/first-time-in-two-decades-new-airlines-are-starting-instead-of-closing-down-jyotiraditya-scindia/articleshow/87660724.cms
https://menafn.com/1103125331/Jet-Airways-to-resume-operations-in-Q1-2022
https://simpleflying.com/jet-airways-100-aircraft-5-years/
https://simpleflying.com/jet-airways-q3-loss/
https://www.business-standard.com/article/companies/defunct-carrier-jet-airways-posts-rs-306-cr-loss-in-september-quarter-121110901693_1.html
https://www.business-standard.com/article/markets/stocks-to-watch-ril-aurobindo-bhel-m-m-jet-airways-idfc-powergrid-121110900189_1.html
https://www.financialexpress.com/market/nykaa-hdfc-zee-media-jet-airways-power-grid-berger-paints-petronet-lng-stocks-in-focus/2366063/
https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/earnings/jet-airways-standalone-september-2021-net-sales-at-rs-41-02-crore-up-313-51-y-o-y-7702891.html
https://www.spokesman.com/stories/2021/nov/11/boeing-set-to-dent-airbus-india-dominance-with-737/
https://www.timesnownews.com/business-economy/industry/article/times-now-summit-2021-jet-airways-will-make-a-comeback-into-indian-skies-akasa-to-take-off-next-year-says-jyotiraditya-scindia/831090


nirav modi
https://m.republicworld.com/india-news/general-news/piyush-goyal-says-few-rotten-eggs-destroyed-credibility-of-countrys-ca-sector.html
https://www.bulletnews.net/akkad-bakkad-rafu-chakkar-review-the-story-of-robbing-people-by-making-fake-banks/
https://www.daijiworld.com/news/newsDisplay%3FnewsID%3D893048
https://www.devdiscourse.com/article/law-order/1805317-hc-seeks-centres-stand-on-bankers-challenge-to-dismissal-from-service
https://www.geo.tv/latest/381560-arif-naqvis-extradition-case-to-be-heard-after-nirav-modi-case-ruling
https://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/cbiand-ed-appointments-that-triggered-controversies-101636954580012.html
https://www.law360.com/articles/1439470/suicide-test-ruling-delays-abraaj-founder-s-extradition-case
https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/trends/current-affairs-trends/nirav-modi-extradition-case-outcome-of-appeal-to-also-affect-pakistani-origin-global-financier-facing-16-charges-of-fraud-and-money-laundering-7717231.html
https://www.thehansindia.com/hans/opinion/news-analysis/uniform-law-needed-for-free-exit-of-rich-businessmen-714566
https://www.thenews.com.pk/print/908374-uk-judge-delays-arif-naqvi-s-extradition-to-us
```